# Why is this method of variable assignment causing issues?

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

How does this style of variable assignment (it's inside an object so the "this" variable refers to said object)):

```
var prop       = this.properties;
var properties = this.properties;
```

Differ from this?

```
var prop = properties = this.properties;
```

When I changed to the latter it caused issues. Is it a referencing issue?

Comment: _"When I changed to the latter it caused issues. Is it a referencing issue?"_ - How are we supposed to answer this without any error message or [mcve] to reproduce the problem?

Comment: in "loose" javascript that may work ... in "strict" javascript it won't, unless `properties` is declared before that code - I guess the sortest code would be `var prop = this.properties, properties = prop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that with the second one, you're trying to assign to a `properties` variable that you haven't declared. The `var` only applies to `prop`, not `properties` because `properties` is on the right-hand side of the `=` after `prop`, so it's part of the initializer for `prop`. Here's how it's grouped:

```
var prop = (properties = this.properties);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−− initializer for `prop`
```

In loose mode, that means you're falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) — it creates a *global* called `properties`. In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), assigning to an undeclared identifier is the error it always should have been. (All new code should be written using strict mode.)

You can declare multiple variables with `var`, etc., but you can't assign to them all using the same value source (without repeating it).

You could do:

```
var prop, properties;
prop = properties = this.properties;
```

if you liked. Or alternatively:

```
var prop = this.properties, properties = prop;
```

That works because the initializers in a `var` (or `let` or `const`) with multiple declarations are executed in source code order, left-to-right, so `prop = this.properties` happens before `properties = prop` does.

---

Side note: `var` shouldn't be used in new code, use `let` or `const`. (If you have to support obsolete JavaScript engines, you can transpile modern code to ES5.)